# Determine all primes such that $p^2\mid 11^{p^{2}} + 1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Determine all primes p such that $p^2\mid 11^{p^{2}} + 1$.

I know to use Fermat, but what exactly should I do?

Comment: If anything, use Euler's theorem and not Fermat's.

Comment: @Jakobian do you have a suggestion on a solution then?

Comment: My mistake, Fermat's theorem works here better. Use Fermat's theorem and reduce the exponent. Then it's just matter of checking all the possibilities.

Comment: @Jakobian That makes more sense, do you mind expanding on that a little more

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, $p\ne 11\implies\gcd(p,11)=1\implies 11^p\equiv 11\pmod{p}$ and thus $$11^p\times 11^p\times\cdots\mbox{$p$ times}\cdots\times11^p\equiv 11^p\pmod{p}$$Therefore,$$11^{p^{2}}\equiv11^p\equiv11\pmod{p}\implies11^{p^2}+1\equiv12\pmod{p}$$but $p\mid11^{p^2}+1$ and hence,
$$12\equiv0\pmod{p}\implies p=2,3$$

Answer (score 1):

$11^2\not|11^{121}+1$ obviously so $p\ne{11}$
$$(11^p)^p+1\equiv (11)^p+1\equiv11+1=12=2^2\cdot3\pmod {p}$$ It follows possible values $p=2,3$.

►$p=2$ is not possible because $$11^4+1=14642=2\cdot7321$$ so  $4\not|11^4+1$.

►$p=3$ is the only solution because
$$11^9+1=(9+2)^9+1\equiv2^9+1=8^3+1\\11^9+1\equiv(-1)^3+1\equiv0\pmod9$$ then $p=3$ is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $p\neq 11$.
$$p^2|11^{p^2}+1\implies p|11^{p^2}+1$$ From Fermat's theorem we have that $$11^{p^2}+1\equiv 11+1 = 12 \ \mod{p}. $$
This would mean that $p|12$, so $p = 2$ or $p = 3$. There's $3$ possibilities, $2, 3, 11$, now check which one satisfies the desired statement.